# Display empty XML tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I am getting an XML from the database if the tag not having any value then tag will be `<tag />`. Please see the sample XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <Header>
        <To Qualifier="P">XXXXXX</To>
        <From Qualifier="D">YYYYYYYYY</From>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <TestData>
            <Date>mm-dd-yyyy</Date>
            <Identifier></Identifier>
         </TestData>    
    </Body>
</Message>
```

It displays like

[image]

but expected should be

[image]

Please help me on this

Below is the C# Code used

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNode xmlnode;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"<FilePath>", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    xmldoc.Load(fs);
    xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
    TreeNode tNode;
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}

private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
{
    XmlNode xNode;
    TreeNode tNode;
    XmlNodeList nodeList;
    int i = 0;
    if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
    {
        nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
        for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
            tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
            AddNode(xNode, tNode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not debug your code, step though it and finally find the point where you add/set an empty string to the tree? You could even use data breakpoints.

Comment: @Keim, Have you down voted. Is there any information missing or the question is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var value = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString()
inTreeNode.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? inXmlNode.Name : value;
```